# SQL Transpose Rows to undefined number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transpose

I have a table containing graduate ids, degree titles and graduation years. The table can contain any number of rows for each graduate.

[image: Current Table structure]

I would like to create a view that would transpose all the rows into as many columns as required, with 'null' being entered in columns where there is no data.

[image: Desired output]

I have seen this question asked quite a few times on here but I'm afraid they have either been not marked as answered or I don't understand the solution. So I have asked the question again in the hope that using my table structure I will better understand the solution.

Any help as always is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
This doesn't have to be a view

Comment: Can you please provide sql for table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic ways of doing this is well described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server/15745076#15745076), but applying that to more than one column in a dynamic fashion when you want the columns in a certain order (degree1, year1, degree2, year2, etc...) can be a bit tricky.

This is one way to do it and as I believe the code is pretty self-explanatory if you have looked at the answer I linked above I won't explain it further:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @title_cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @year_cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @header AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
    @title_cols = ISNULL(@title_cols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(rn),
    @year_cols  = ISNULL(@year_cols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(CONCAT('y',rn)),
    @header = ISNULL(@header + ',','') + CONCAT('MAX(',QUOTENAME(rn) ,') AS "Degree Title ', rn, '", MAX(',QUOTENAME(CONCAT('y',rn)) ,') AS "Graduation Year ', rn, '"')
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Graduate ID] ORDER BY [Degree Title], [Graduation Year]) 
  FROM Graduates
) GRADS

SET @sql =
  N'SELECT [Graduate ID], ' + @header + '
    FROM (
       SELECT *,
          title = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Graduate ID] ORDER BY [Graduation Year]),
          year = CONCAT(''y'',ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Graduate ID] ORDER BY [Graduation Year])) 
       FROM Graduates) g
    PIVOT(MAX([Degree Title]) FOR title IN (' + @title_cols + ')) AS Titles
    PIVOT(MAX([Graduation Year]) FOR year IN (' + @year_cols + ')) AS Years
    GROUP BY [Graduate ID]'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a93e/1)

The query uses the `concat()` function which is available in SQL Server 2012 and later, so if you are using an older version you would have to change that part to a "normal" string concatenation with casts.

I'm sure the query can be improved in many ways, but I'll leave that as an exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with ug as
(select * from Graduates where Degree Title LIKE "B%")
with pg as
(select * from Graduates where Degree Title LIKE "M%")
with pg1 as
(select * from Graduates where Degree Title LIKE "P%")

select 
ug.id as Graduate ID
, ug.Degree Title as Degree Title 1
, ug. Graduation Year as Graduation Year 1
, pg1.Degree Title as Degree Title 2
, pg1. Graduation Year as Graduation Year 2
, pg2.Degree Title as Degree Title 3
, pg2. Graduation Year as Graduation Year 3
from ug 
left join pg1 
on ug.Graduate ID= pg1.Graduate ID
left join pg2
on ug.Graduate ID= pg2.Graduate ID
```